# Getting the error "Column does not allow nulls"

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, ado.net

I'm applying ADO.net and want to add a new row to a DataTable placed in a DataSet. I then try to update the database with the new row by using the update method of a DataAdapter. The error I'm getting is

> Column "RECORD_ID does not allow nulls.

`RECORD_ID` is the primary key column of my source table which has an autonumber datatype. I'm using MS Access 2007. Any ideas anyone how to solve this avoiding hacks?

Comment: show us your code, or should we take guesses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column RECORD_ID is primary key, that means it should have unique values different from null every time. You are adding dataRow to DataSet but forget to set the row["Record_ID"].

You need something like that:

```
row["RECORD_ID"]= Guid.NewGuid();//if RECORD_ID is type of GUID
row["RECORD_ID"]= LastUniqueID+1; // if RECORD_ID is int.
```